# Sakurai's derivation of the time-reversal operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, symmetry, time-reversal-symmetry

I am reading the section in Sakurai's Modern Quantum Mechanics (2nd Edition) on the time-reversal operator $\Theta$ in quantum mechanics. He provides a short derivation of the properties that the time-reversal operator $\Theta$ should have. In particular, in equation (4.4.31) on page 291 it is stated that the time-reversal operator must obey

$$ \Theta H = H \Theta \quad (*) $$

where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the system. This result is true when acting on any states $|\psi\rangle$ in the Hilbert space and it also appears that no particular form of $H$ was assumed. At first glance this property is telling me that $[H , \Theta]=0$ for all Hamiltonians, in other words all Hamiltonians have time-reversal invariance!

This is obviously not true and in fact later in the book theorem 4.2 *assumes* a time-reversal invariant Hamiltonian implying that not all Hamiltonians are time-reversal invariant.

One would assume time-reversal invariance means $[H,\Theta] = 0$ so I am unsure how this differs from (*) above. Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Generically the Hamiltonian does not need to commute with the time-reversal operator. For instance for an electron in an external magnetic field, time-reversal is broken. $[H,\Theta]=H\Theta - \Theta H$ obviously.

Comment: From what I understand, Sakurai says that $\Theta$ ought to not be unitary for the time-reversal symmetry to make sense, and assumes it to be antiunitary, which leads to the case where $[H, \Theta] = 0$, but as I understand it's not compelled for $\Theta$ to be antiunitary, the only restriction is that it can't be unitary. This is just how I interpret what Sakurai says, so I'm not 100% sure of it.

Comment: @Mr.Nobody the point is that previously he showed that if $\Theta$ is unitary then we get $\Theta H = - H \Theta$, and then he goes on to derive that we also get $\Theta H = H \Theta$, therefore it cannot be unitary. The equation the OP marked with $(*)$ is *not* the general case, and Sakurai uses it during this proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it also appears that no particular form of $H$ was assumed.

This is not the case. In page $290$ Sakurai says:

> If the motion obeys symmetry under time reversal, we expect the preceding ket to be the same as $$\Theta|\alpha,t_0;t=-\delta t\rangle$$

So we are beginning with the assumption of time reversal invariance. So if the condition $[H,\Theta]=0$ holds, then the system is time reversal invariant. This means not all  Hamiltonians are symmetric under time reversal.

In fact take the case of angular momentum in a magnetic field: $H=\mu \hat{J}\cdot B$. You can easily see that this Hamiltonian is not symmetric under time reversal.